# How do I pass javac multiple command-line arguments, some of which include colon, without breaking Maven release plugin?

Tags: java, maven, javac, maven-release-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin

I want to make my Maven build fail when I forget to declare serialVersionUIDs in a `Serializable` class. With `javac`, that's easy:

```
$ javac -Xlint:serial -Werror Source.java
```

Directly translating that to Maven doesn't work:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:serial -Werror</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The `compilerArgument` is quoted, so `javac` receives only one argument, containing `-Xlint:serial -Werror`, instead of `-Xlint:serial` and `-Werror` as separate arguments. So you read the docs, and find `compilerArguments`:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <Xlint:serial />
                    <Werror />
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This looks weird - the colon makes `serial` element in the `Xlint` namespace, which isn't declared anywhere - but it works... until you want to do a release:

> `$ mvn release:prepare`
>
> `org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare (default-cli) on project my-project: Error reading POM: Error on line 58: The prefix "Xlint" for element "Xlint:serial" is not bound.`

Apparently, the regular POM reader handles XML namespaces in another way than the one used by the release plugin.

So how do I pass `javac` multiple command-line switches when some of those switches contain characters which aren't valid for plain XML elements, without breaking the release plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that while spaces are escaped in `compilerArgument`, the same isn't true for quotes. So, if you surround the spaces in the argument with quotes, you get two arguments:

```
<compilerArgument>-Xlint:serial" "-Werror</compilerArgument>
```

This invokes `javac "-Xlint:serial" "-Werror"` rather than `javac "-Xlint:serial -Werror"`.

There's nothing in the docs about this that I can find.

Comment: That's interesting. Is it a bug or an intended change in behavior?

Comment: I tried
<compilerArguments>-classpath:classes" "-d:classes</compilerArgument
And here is what I have:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5:compile (default-compile) on project my-project-usage: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5:compile: Cannot assign value '-classpath:classes" "-d:classes' (type: class java.lang.String) to protected java.util.Maporg.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.compilerArguments: Can not set java.util.Map field. HELLLLLP !!!

Comment: That was about maven-compiler-plugin too.

Comment: It's `<compilerArgument>`, not `<compilerArguments>`. They work very differently.

Answer (score 5):

See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArgs

and http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html

Maven 3.1 or later

```
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                        </processors>
                        <compilerArgs>
                          <arg>-verbose</arg>
                          <arg>-Aeclipselink.persistencexml=src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml</arg>
                        </compilerArgs>
```

or Maven 3.0 or older

```
      <compilerArguments>
        <verbose />
      </compilerArguments>
      <compilerArgument>-Aeclipselink.persistencexml=src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml</compilerArgument>
```

Comment: The compilerArgs won't be available until version  3.1

Comment: a) it came out 2 years ago b) I do have an "or" section

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bug in maven-compiler-plugin, I submitted an issue to developers: [MCOMPILER-178](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-178)

Answer (score 1):

In relation to [Kalpesh Soni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339056/how-do-i-pass-javac-multiple-command-line-arguments-some-of-which-include-colon/23743186#23743186):

Note for Maven 3.1 or later according to the example from http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html:

```
<compilerArgs>
    <arg>-verbose</arg>
    <arg>-Xlint:all,-options,-path</arg>
</compilerArgs>
```

The above is great unless you want to pass an additional param that requires space character. In my case it was `-bootclasspath /path/to/custom/rt.jar`. In such a case you have to split this string on every space and pass every part as a new `<arg />` in order not to get `Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: ...` So the working example is:

```
<compilerArgs>
    <arg>-verbose</arg>
    <arg>-Xlint:all,-options,-path</arg>
    <arg>-bootclasspath</arg><arg>/path/to/custom/rt.jar</arg>
</compilerArgs>
```

Comment: holy hell thank you for posting this answer. 3 hours of my life chasing down this error with bootclasspath. what a mess