# How to compile using -Xlint:unchecked in a Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

In NetBeans 7.2, I'm having trouble finding how to compile using -Xlint:unchecked in a Maven project. Under an Ant project, you can change compiler flags by going to Project Properties ->  Compiling, but Maven projects don't seem to have any such option.

Is there any way to configure the IDE to compile with such flags using Maven?

Comment: If you need to pass multiple arguments, you may recieve an error with `<compilerArgument>`. See this answer for alternative `<compilerArgs><arg></arg>...<compilerArgs>`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23743186/257299

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I guess you can set compiler arguments in your pom.xml. Please refer this http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html

```
 <compilerArgument>-Xlint:unchecked</compilerArgument>
```

Comment: I've created a small test program that should generate a warning about the usage of static methods, but I can't seem to get maven to generate any warnings about it. Gist with sample program and pom file posted here -> https://gist.github.com/influenza/5145598

Comment: @RonDahlgren: why would you expect this to throw a warning?

Comment: @haylem - Accessing a static field or method should generate a warning with that enabled. This is a details of the javac being used, but it's common: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcompiler%2Fref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm and http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dstudio/v3r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcompiler%2Fref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm

Comment: @RonDahlgren: right, it's a common warning, but it's not one that's reported by javac. It's reported by the Eclipse compiler and a few others, and by many additional code style checkers, but it won't be reported by javac. You could have maven use the eclipse compiler instead if you prefer.

Comment: The linked page suggests that the <CompilerArgument> entry should go in the <CompilerArguments> group.  Which seemed logical.    As per the link below it actually goes in the <configuration> group. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215781/how-do-i-compile-with-xlintunchecked

Answer (score 67):

I want to elaborate on @Nishant's answer. The `compilerArgument` tag needs to go inside `plugin/configuration` tag. Here is a full example:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
      <testSource>1.8</testSource>
      <testTarget>1.8</testTarget>
      <compilerArgument>-Xlint:unchecked</compilerArgument>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Giving the context parameters need to  go into is an important part of an helpful answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This works for me...

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>11</source>
            <target>11</target>
            <compilerArguments>
                <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
            </compilerArguments>
            <compilerArgs>
                <arg>-Xlint:unchecked</arg>   <-------this right here ---->
            </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score -2):

The pom file information is spot on. I had the additional challenge of building someone else's Maven project in Jenkins and not having access to the pom file repository.

I created a pre-build step to insert the compiler parameter into the pom file after downloading it from git, for example

```
sed -i 's|/target> *$|/target>\n<compilerArgument>\n-Xlint:deprecation\n</compilerArgument>|' $WORKSPACE/pom.xml
```

Comment: Bad solution.  Fork the project.  And send them a pull request with the change.