# Java deprecated API using Xlint:deprecation

Tags: maven-2, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I want to remove all use of deprecated API's in my code.  But for few API's I get this message upon compiling.

```
[Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.]
```

With what maven command can I use to get the details of the deprecated API?

What should my approach be to finding the deprecated API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compile using -Xlint:unchecked in a Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449251/how-to-compile-using-xlintunchecked-in-a-maven-project)

Comment: The linked question is *almost* identical ... and the solution is the same.